# Clickable phone numbers in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Hey guys, I have an app where I pull text from a database and place it into a TableView. Is there a simple way to have the TableView identify phone numbers within the cell and allow users to click on it to call the number?

Example: (inside the UITableViewCell)

> We are a store that sells premium cat food. To contact us call 123.567.9012 or visit www.whatever.com.

I would like the user to be able to just click on the phone number and it brings up the "call" or "cancel" popup.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're after is data detection. `UITextView` performs data detection providing it the text is uneditable. You can create a `UITableViewCell` subclass that contains a `UITextField`. Have a look at the `dataDetectorTypes` in the [`UITextView` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html).

Both `UITableView` and `UITextField` are both subclasses of `UIScrollView` so you'll have to pay attention to scrolling behaviour.

Comment: any way i could do this with a UILabel? or better yet, is there any easy way to integrate this into a uitableviewcell?

Comment: You could attached a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to a `UILabel`. The gesture recogniszer would invoke a method for making the phone call. The problem with this is that the all of the text will become tap-able not just the phone number (this may not be an issue, depending on what the text is). The `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` properties of `UITableViewCell` are just `UILabel`s.

Comment: There is a problem with putting a UITextView in a table cell with dataDetectorTypes enabled. It works great when the tap is on a link. But when the tap is NOT on a link, I would like didSelectRowAtIndexPath to be called, as normal. Any way to get this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is, use a UITextView and set the data detectors accordingly. Disable editing. Here is a simple example screenshot. Cells were made with IB. Clicking on the URL will open Safari, the phone number will only work on a device.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For this you can create a button and set title to your phone number and in its action use this code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://8004664411"]];
```

and to open url use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

As it was already stated before this can be easily achieved with the **usage** of a **UITextView** by setting in the Interface Builder **properties**:

```
Detection: Phone Numbers
Editable: False
Scrolling Enabled: False
User Interaction Enabled: True
```

Please bear in mind that phone number detection **only works** if you test it in a **real device**. If testing in the **Simulator it wont work**.